# how to bind images stored in Binary Form in the database with the Ad-Rotator?

Tags: adrotator

I have  Some Images Stored in database in binary form and i want to bind them with adrotator.
i know that if we are storing the URL of the image in databse then we can easily bind it,,,but i dont know how to bind images in binary form with adrotator.
Anybody here please tell me???

Answer (score 0):

you can easily retrieve image from Sql server using query with  FileStream to  write to byte array.

[Check this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImageSaveInDataBase.aspx)

**EDIT**

EXAMPLE

> SqlCommand cmdSelect=new  SqlCommand("select Picture  from TABLENAME where  ID=@ID",this.sqlConnection1);
>           cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@ID",SqlDbType.Int,4);
>
> ```
>     this.sqlConnection1.Open();
>     byte[] barrImg=(byte[])cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar();
>     string strfn=Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
>     FileStream fs=new FileStream(strfn, 
>                       FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
>     fs.Write(barrImg,0,barrImg.Length);
>     fs.Flush();
>     fs.Close();
>     Image IMG=Image.FromFile(strfn);
> ```

**EDIT 2**

[go through the answer](http://dotnet.itags.org/web-forms/70925/)

Comment: But how will add this image to a adrotator.